Why the type is not correct in my action?
Haskell newbie here . I'm trying to ask a value and retrieve it in a different method, but I'm having a problem with the types that I don't fully get
main= do 
askStrength

askStrength :: () -> IO Int
askStrength = do
   putStr "Strength : "
   strength <- readLn::Int
   return strength

I am getting the following error
ghci> :l testPickCharacteristic.hs 
[1 of 2] Compiling Main             ( testPickCharacteristic.hs, interpreted )

testPickCharacteristic.hs:3:1: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type: IO t0
                  with actual type: () -> IO Int
    • When checking the type of the IO action ‘main’
  |
3 | main= do 
  | ^^^^

testPickCharacteristic.hs:8:4: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type: () -> IO Int
                  with actual type: IO b0
    • In a stmt of a 'do' block: putStr "Strength : "
      In the expression:
        do putStr "Strength : "
           strength <- readLn :: Int
           return strength
      In an equation for ‘askStrength’:
          askStrength
            = do putStr "Strength : "
                 strength <- readLn :: Int
                 return strength
  |
8 |    putStr "Strength : "
  |    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

testPickCharacteristic.hs:9:16: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘Int’ with actual type ‘IO a0’
    • In a stmt of a 'do' block: strength <- readLn :: Int
      In the expression:
        do putStr "Strength : "
           strength <- readLn :: Int
           return strength
      In an equation for ‘askStrength’:
          askStrength
            = do putStr "Strength : "
                 strength <- readLn :: Int
                 return strength
  |
9 |    strength <- readLn::Int
  |                ^^^^^^

where am I failing ? Thanks .

() -> means it takes a parameter, but askStrength doesn't take any parametres.

readLn :: Int is wrong, that's not an integer constant, it's an IO action that produces an integer. Use readLn :: IO Int instead.

Nice . Thanks a lot . Both answers saved my day . Thanks

@chi Or just don't annotate readLn at all, since the type signature of main makes it inferrable.
